# how to filter nested array of a document mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb, filter, nested, bson

How do I filter an Array of an object which also has objects again using Java (Bson Documents).

For example I've a user which has an array = followed Users. Now I want to filter a specific user from that list how do I do that ? 
[here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEZk5.png)

I tried smth like this but I just don't have any idea since this is getting more complex :

```
Document filter = new Document("follows", new Document("$elemMatch", eq("uID", uID)));
```

Comment: Did you try aggregation pipeline in which you can unwind follows array and then put  a match conditon?

Comment: I don't know how to do this with java but with javascript you can do it like this `db.collection.find({
  follows: {
    $elemMatch: {
      uID: "int3"
    }
  }
},
{
  follows: {
    $elemMatch: {
      uID: "int3"
    }
  }
})`... You can try to solve the syntax for this in java